# Unable to find selected index in ListView for windows phone

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-phone

I am facing a trouble in getting item's index in Listview. I have a child element inside data template like the following:

```
<ListView x:Name="ptype_gw" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  ItemsSource="{Binding PropertyTypes}" >

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding title}" Style="{ThemeResource menu_heading_green}" Grid.Row="0" />
                        <GridView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding childs}" >
                            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <RadioButton  Name="PropertyTypeRadio" Content="{Binding title}" Tag="{Binding}" GroupName="Types" Checked="RadioButton_Checked"  Background="White" Foreground="Black" BorderBrush="Black" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                        </GridView>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Now i Need to get the index of selected item whenever radio button is checked. I  have tried the following code:

```
 var item = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext;

            int index = ptype_gw.Items.IndexOf(item);
```

But it didn't helped me.

Comment: Did you mean to get the textbox content when checkbox is checked?
Could you please share the entire code ie the checked event?

Did you debug and check whether the item is returning the exact selected item?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Vishakh. I just want to get the selected index of the list on checking of radio button.

Answer (score 0):

That’s very simple.
Bind the SelectedItem of list to a property in view model. Say **SelectedItem**. When user selects an item, the **SelectedItem** property will hold the details of current selected item.

Now handle the **radio button checked or unchecked event** as per your requirement. When the event occurs, check the **SelectedItem** property.
I am talking about MVVM case.

If you are writing code in your xaml.cs itself, then get the selected  property of listbox directly like this in the radio button checked event.

```
ListBoxName.SelectedItem
ListBoxName.SelectedIndex
```